# Reviewing my leap year program

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning ruby using Chris Pine's tutorial: https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/?Chapter=06

Basically the task is to write a leap year program:

> Write a program which will ask for a starting year and an ending year, and then puts all of the leap years between them (and including them, if they are also leap years). Leap years are years divisible by four (like 1984 and 2004). However, years divisible by 100 are not leap years (such as 1800 and 1900) unless they are divisible by 400 (like 1600 and 2000, which were in fact leap years).

Here is the program I've written:

```
puts "leap years program"
puts ""
puts "what is the starting year?"
startYear = gets.to_i
puts "what is the ending year?"
while (endYear = gets.to_i) < startYear
    puts "ending year should be later than starting year, please re-input:"
end
while startYear < endYear
    while ((startYear % 4 == 0 and startYear % 100 != 0) or (startYear % 100 == 0 and startYear % 400 == 0))
        puts startYear.to_s
        startYear = startYear + 1       
    end
    startYear = startYear + 1
end
```

Why do I need to write `startYear = startYear + 1` twice - once in the inner while loop and once in the outer while loop?

Also, any other pointers and tips to improve my program would be appreciated.

Comment: Trace the program's execution, use pencil and paper to track values.

Comment: Why do you even _have_ two nested loops here? That should be _one_ single loop to go over the years from start to end, and inside that an _if_ condition that determines whether the current year is a leap year or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the condition 'startYear < endYear' in the inner while loops conditions '    while ((startYear % 4 == 0 and startYear % 100 != 0) or (startYear % 100 == 0 and startYear % 400 == 0))' so you no more need the outer loop, and you just have one loop.

Answer (score 0):

@Jimmy:

The way you have your program written, if you *didn't* increment startYear within your inner loop, it would be an infinite loop.  The first time you found a leap year and got into your inner loop, you would never exit it because the inner loop condition would always be true.

If you entered the inner loop with startYear = 2000 and never incremented it within that loop, your output would be similar to:

2000
2000
2000
...

So you increment startYear by 1, making it 2001, which fails the inner loop condition.  Then, you increment startYear by 1 again in your outer loop before testing it against the inner loop condition again.  This ensures that you are not testing the same year twice.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an inner loop when all you really need to do is check once per iteration in the outer loop. So, you might try using a conditional inside the loop:

```
while startYear < endYear
    if (startYear % 4 == 0 and startYear % 100 != 0) or
        (startYear % 100 == 0 and startYear % 400 == 0)
       puts startYear.to_s     
    end
    startYear = startYear + 1
end
```

I hate while loops, because I often find them harder to predict. Here's how I might avoid using one here:

```
(endYear - startYear).times do |year|
    if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0 or
        year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 == 0
        puts year.to_s
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently on while loops so the program was meant for practice. The if loop inside the while loop makes a ton of sense, idk why i didn't think of that earlier - it seems like best practice.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is better:

```
puts "leap years program".center(60)
puts ""
puts 'Please type a starting year: '
starting = gets.to_i
puts 'Please type a ending year: '
  while (ending = gets.to_i) < starting
puts 'ending year should be later than starting year, please re-input:'
  end
puts 'All leap years below:'
  while starting <= ending
    if (starting%100 != 0 and starting%4 == 0) or (starting%100 == 0 and starting%400 == 0)
      puts starting
    end
  starting = starting + 1
  end
```

Comment: you don't explain what you changed. this does not help a newbie